# Get easy commenter and Bootstrap to work with same version of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 and jQuery version 1.10.2

I am also using easy commenter and they require jQuery version 1.5.2 I have tried to just keep version 1.10.2 , just keep version 1.5.2 and keep both of them. But in every case one of them does not behave as expected. With version 1.5.2 the collapsible menu in header stops working with version 1.10.2 easy commenter stops working. How should I deal with this problem?
Here is a link to the page I am working on http://8mags.com/lessons/php/phpcalendar.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the newer JQuery plus the [migrate plugin](http://jquery.com/download/#jquery-migrate-plugin)

Comment: If it works, this is definitely better than including jQuery twice.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is: If the "easy commenter" plugin doesn't work with a current version of jQuery, rather than one from three years ago, you want to find a different plugin or take the existing one and modify it so that it works with the current jQuery. The differences between 1.5.2 and 1.11.2 (the current version as of this writing) aren't really all that big, and are easily updated.

If you don't want to do that (why not?), then you *can* use both versions of jQuery on your page, but it doubles the size of an already-large library, increasing page load time.

Here's how:

```
<script src="jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script src="easy-commenter.js"></script>
<script>
var $old = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<!-- all your other plugins and such, including bootstrap -->
```

You load jQuery 1.5.2, load the easy commenter plugin, then use `noConflict` to release both the `$` and `jQuery` symbols, and load jQuery 1.11.2.

When you want to use the easy commenter plugin, use `$old` rather than `$`.

Comment: Your solution appears to be nice. But at present I am just learning jQuery and javascript and I would prefer to do it the easy way. Thanx for the answer though.

Comment: @ﱞﱞﱞﱞﱞﱞ: If the migrate plugin works, that's the better way to go if you aren't going to fix the easy commenter plugin. *(Please change your username to something legible.)*